# Angular sub urls not opening on hosting

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am facing one issue which is when I upload my angular app to my hosting it's not opening sub URLs, for example, https://mywebsite.com it's opening but https://mywebsite.com/pricing it's not opening directly user need to open website first then go to another page.

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mobile App Development Services | Web Development Services | Logo Design Services</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/img/favicon.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you build with the --base-href and --output-url flags?

Comment: i simple build by ng build --prod